# Cannot find downloaded files

Tags: downloading

My phone is a Galaxy S3 i9300 and is rooted. I do most of the time download files via the Internet. So the files I downloaded are in the `documents` folder. The weird part is after I check it in my file manager, the downloaded file is nowhere to be found. I am 100% sure that I finished the download. Have anyone experience this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the app you use, it may be in a different folder. I know when I am looking for a file (photo or download), I have to check my internal partition "Download" folder, my external (SD Card) "Download" folder, or sometimes even on the root of either partition.

If you used a standard browser (Stock browser, Opera, Firefox, Chrome, etc), they all should have their own in-app download manager that lists the files you have downloaded. You should be able to open the file within the browser app; if you can't, then you know the file isn't downloaded.